# Strange vertical space in tikz text node

Tags: sectioning, chapters, line-spacing

I am using chapter decorations from template "Legrand Orange book". But I am getting very strange vertical spacing with it. See the picture. because of capital letter **H** spacing between 3rd and 4th line is way bigger than previos one where there is no "above-line" letters.

So, this small vertical spacing is weird for me... Am I wrong? I would like to change vertical spacing to normal (where there is a gap for capital letters)

[image]

Here is minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{prpl}{RGB}{150, 120, 182} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-5cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=prpl,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=45pt]{\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-5cm) node[text width=16cm] {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter. #1};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Исследование функций одной переменной при помощи первой и второй производных на монотонность, локальные экстремумы, выпуклость. Необходимые условия, достаточные условия.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the box with the rounded corners supposed to bleed off the page? What size is it supposed to be?

Comment: @sgmoye yes, it's supposed to bleed off the page... I am fine with both variants of size: fixed one (which I do have now) and the second one which takes textheight as a parameter...

Comment: You are nesting `tikzpicture`s which is not supported. Moreover, you are nesting one `remember picture, overlay` in another, which doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @cfr this is how it is done in template itself. I thought there is hidden sence in it :-)

Comment: @Lust_For_Love Whenever people say 'template', expect trouble. The majority are extremely poorly written and cause deep, mysterious and generally quite horrible problems sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what it should look like. Here's a way of getting the 'correct' line spacing i.e. the proper line-spacing for `\huge`. If you want something different, you can use `\fontsize{<dimen>}{<dimen>}\selectfont` in place of `\huge`, where the first number gives the point size of the font and the second the baseline skip e.g. `{12pt}{14pt}`.

I've eliminated the nested `tikzpicture`s as this is not supported and known to cause problems. This is even more so with a nested `remember picture, overlay`, which makes no sense at all.

You might find `tikzpagenodes` useful to avoid the use of internal `geometry` dimensions.

```
\documentclass[russian]{book} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\definecolor{prpl}{RGB}{150, 120, 182} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node (n) at (\Gm@lmargin,-\Gm@tmargin) [ inner sep=3mm, fill=white, fill opacity=0.5, text width={\textwidth-6mm}, text opacity=1, font=\huge\sffamily\bfseries, text=black]{\thechapter. #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw [line width=2pt, rounded corners=15pt, prpl] (n.north -| current page.east) -| (n.south west) -- (n.south -| current page.east); 
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \bigskip\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Исследование функций одной переменной при помощи первой и второй производных на монотонность, локальные экстремумы, выпуклость. Необходимые условия, достаточные условия.}
\kant[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The lines are just from `showframe` for illustration and debugging. Obviously, you should remove this option when you're happy with the placement.

As an example, `\huge` means 20pt font with 25pt skip. Substituting `\fontsize{20pt}{22pt}\selectfont` in the code for `\huge` closes the lines up:

[image: squishier output]

Comment: I tried my hand at this (fixing the nested `tikzpicture`s and using `tikzpagenodes.sty`). The problem is that `remember picture,overlay` makes the `tikzpicture` take up no space on the page so that text that follows the chapter head overprints the chapter head. Removing `remember picture,overlay` in my attempts works, but the log complains of an overfull `\hbox`, unsurprisingly. In short, I couldn't find a way around this, outside of a hacky `\vspace` for each occurrence of a `\chapter`.

Comment: @sgmoye I can look later, but the use of `\vspace` is not hacky here. In any case, you needed this with your original code already, so that's not knew. Probably the best way is to typeset the chapter title in place and overlay the border. That way, you know how much extra space to allow because it will always be the same amount.

Comment: @sgmoye Please see edit above. I think this is probably simplest: split the picture and overlay the border. This means the spacing is correct regardless of the height/depth of the chapter title, which will obviously vary. At least, it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Nice. Wish I'd thought of that...

Comment: @sgmoye Thanks for the prompt. Obviously wasn't thinking about the actual text when I wrote the original version ....

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt -- it works but seems hacky. The problem is getting text following the chapter head to be located correctly. Please see the comments in the code. I'd like to see a somewhat less hacky solution!

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{prpl}{RGB}{150, 120, 182} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newsavebox{\tmpbox}
\newlength{\tmpht}

%% Put the text of the chapter head into an lrbox.
%% Use the lrbox in \@makechapterhead;
%% measure the lrbox to arrive at a \vspace that
%% gets the text of the chapter out the way of
%% the chapter head.

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\begin{lrbox}{\tmpbox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \raggedright\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}\thechapter. #1
    \end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%% The chapter head occupies no space on the page
    \node[anchor=north west,
    rounded corners=15pt,
    draw=prpl!50,
    line width=2pt,
    inner sep=6pt] at (current page text area.north west)
        {\usebox{\tmpbox}\hspace*{22cm}}; %% change '22cm' to suit
\end{tikzpicture}%
\settoheight{\tmpht}{\usebox{\tmpbox}}%
\vspace{\dimexpr\tmpht + 1in}% Adjust 1in to suit
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Исследование функций одной переменной при помощи первой и второй производных на монотонность, локальные экстремумы, выпуклость. Необходимые условия, достаточные условия.}

\section{This is a section}

More text.

\end{document}
```

--

[image]

Comment: I don't see why you think this is hacky, to be honest. Maybe it is a bit more of a faff to set-up, but measuring the size of boxes is the point of TeX, isn't it? :-)